# Object Oriented Database Support in IntelliJ?

Tags: database, oop, intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ officially support any object oriented databases for Java (such as Cache, ObjectDB)? (as in they support the database with their own plugins, without third-party plugins).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **Ultimate** version you have this support built in from JetBrains.

See `https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/` and `https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/`. But for this, you have to pay for it.

Comment: Could you send me specific link shows this? The links you included are only general features.

Comment: The links contain examples. NAvigate in documentation for more info.

Comment: I looked around - couldn't find anything.. Don't think you understood my question. I am NOT looking for support for SQL databases - I already know about those. I am looking for support on Object Oriented Databases:  see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database)